# c# cmd se escrever outra coisa mostra uma msg

Tags: c#

Olá eu gostaria de saber como poderia fazer no cmd para que quando se alguém escrevesse qualquer coisa que não seja tree aparecesse uma msg a dizer "o que escreveu" não foi reconhecido...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer uma condição, simples

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "tree")
{
    Console.WriteLine("tree");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("o que escreveu não foi reconhecido!");
}
```